# Create .REG file to edit only single Octet at specific address in Binary Value without affecting other bytes in binary data

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit

Is it possible to create a `.reg` file for Windows 10 to edit only a single octet at a specific address in a binary value consisting of `n` octets without changing the rest of the binary value?

I want to change `"Settings"=binary:` in:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3
```

I only want to change octet `0008` from a value of `02` to `03` and leave all the rest of the data as is:
[image: Edit Binary Value - Screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

1. **Export Registry Key:** *(PowerShell variable)*

   ```powershell
   Reg Export "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3" "$ENV:UserProfile\Documents\StuckRects3.reg"
   ```
2. **Edit Exported Key:** 
    Open `%UserProfile%\Documents\StuckRects3.reg` in a text editor, such as [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), changing the binary value.  *File output will resemble:*

   ```powershell
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKCU\some\registry\keys\binary\output]
    @=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
      00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
      4e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,\
      00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,\
      22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00
   ```
3. **Import Modified Key:** *(PowerShell variable)*

   ```powershell
   Reg Import "$ENV:UserProfile\Documents\StuckRects3.reg"
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  So the only way to do it is through a script?  This cannot be changed from a .REG file directly?

Comment: @MvdM The above is a `.reg` file... Unless you're asking if it's possible through `RegEdit` directly?  You can, but it's safer to export the key first, edit it in a text editor, then re-import since right-clicking the key and selecting _"Modify Binary Data..."_ is less friendly to edits and is way too easy for a user to corrupt the binary data.